# Help replicating a simple calculation in a paper on Asymmetric Number Systems

Tags: notation, arithmetic

This question is rather simple, it boils down to whether I am reading a math paper correctly? I am attempting to read this paper by Jarek Duda on Assyemtric Number Systems and their use in compression of data.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2540v2.pdf

I'm a bit rusty on my math lingo so I tried to replicate the calculations to help me understand them, and I failed. Am I missing something? This is roughly what is on page 7:

> Encoding is
>
> $$
> C(x,s)=
> \left\{
>  \begin{array}{11}
>   \big\lceil\frac{x+1}{1-p}\big\rceil-1  & \mbox{if } s = 0  \\
>   \big\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\big\rfloor & \mbox{if } s = 1 
>  \end{array}
> \text{or}=\Bigg\{
>  \begin{array}{11}
>   \big\lfloor\frac{x}{1-p}\big\rfloor  & \mbox{if } s = 0  \\
>   \big\lceil\frac{x+1}{p}\big\rceil-1 & \mbox{if } s = 1 
>  \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>   For p = 1/2 it is the standard binary numeral system with switched digits.
>   The starting values for this formula and p = 0.3 are presented in bottom-right of Fig. 1.  Here is an example of encoding process by inserting succeeding symbols:
>   $$
> 1\xrightarrow{1}
> 3\xrightarrow{0}
> 5\xrightarrow{0}
> 8\xrightarrow{1}
> 26\xrightarrow{0}
> 38\xrightarrow{1}
> 128\xrightarrow{0}
> 184\xrightarrow{0}
> 264...
> $$

I tried to calculate this sequence myself, and I got different results

```
s: 1 x: 1 x': 3
s: 0 x: 3 x': 5
s: 0 x: 5 x': 8
s: 1 x: 8 x': 26
s: 0 x: 26 x': 38
s: 1 x: 38 x': 126
s: 0 x: 126 x': 181
s: 0 x: 181 x': 259
```

Here is my calculation program in the Python language:

```
from fractions import Fraction as F
import math

def C(s,x):
        p=F(3,10)
        if s==0: return math.ceil(F(x+1,1-p))-1
        elif s==1: return math.floor(F(x,p))
        else: print("error")

x = 1
for s in 1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0:
        print('s:',s,'x:',x,end='')
        x = C(s,x)
        print(" x':",x)
```

Thanks

Comment: Using Maple I can reproduce your sequence. The other encoding procedure (the 'or' parts) give completely different results. I could not find these encoding procedures at https://github.com/JarekDuda/AsymmetricNumeralSystemsToolkit, perhaps you should email the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. This was historically the first variant (uABS from 2006), which [has some advantages](https://encode.ru/threads/1821-Asymetric-Numeral-System?p=41539&viewfull=1#post41539) but also [rounding issue](https://encode.ru/threads/1821-Asymetric-Numeral-System?p=54750&viewfull=1#post54750) one need to be careful about.

**It is interesting question if uABS approach can be expanded to a larger alphabet?**

In practice there are used large alphabet: tabled tANS (2007), or much more crude rANS (2013).

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake, I don't know where it came from.